# How to save a calculation as a default value in a PostgreSQL's table column

Tags: postgresql, default-value, calculation

I have a PostgreSQL's table with three columns: **quantity**, **price** and **total**.

Total saves a calculation: **total = quantity * price**.

I would like to saves that calculation as a **default value** for **total** column. Excel can do it (I know it is not the same), so I am thinking something similar.

Example:

**quantity: 2**

**price: 5**

**total: 10** (quantity x price)

Answer (score 4):

You should make the total column NULL-able (allow NULL values). Then add a trigger for INSERT and UPDATE which will compute the NEW.total value if it is NULL.
However, I would advice against using computed columns in your database - it is always better to perform those calculations on the client-side.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tr_insert (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.total IS NULL THEN
    NEW.total = NEW.quantity * NEW.price;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER;

CREATE TRIGGER task_main_tr
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON public.task_main

FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_insert();
```